# How can I use Redis to fetch data from large dataset?

Tags: database, postgresql, redis, architecture, blockchain

I'm working on blockchain explorer where two nodes are running.One to insert data from blockchain to postgres database and another one to fetch using api calls.
Now database entries are reached over million records and single api tooks too much time to fetch data especially when I have to sort and fetch latest records.
I have found redis can be best option but don't know how to place latest records in redis from postgres.

Any idea how can I get latest records fast ?

Comment: You forgot an index.

Comment: I have done indexing but when I try to sort data with joins, indexing is also not giving required result.

Comment: What I am trying to say with this is that your question lacks crucial details, like the table definitions, the slow SQL statements and execution plans. Nobody can give you a useful answer.